# How can I list all Bitbake recipes in a layer filtered by MACHINE?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I'm trying to write a script for a CI system that will build all the recipes (.bb and .bbappend) in a layer.

1. When I try to run `bitbake-layers show-recipes -l my_layer` I get the error:

```
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

    Please set a MACHINE in your local.conf or environment
```

which makes sense. But when I specify the `MACHINE` the recipes are listed regardless of what's in the recipe's `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE`. How do I get it to filter by `MACHINE`?

2. `bitbake-layers show-recipes -l my_layer` only shows me `.bb` files in the layer. I've also got `.bbappend` files that modify `.bb` from open source layers like [meta-openembedded](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded) which I want to build too. How can I get `bitbake-layers` to list these too?

Comment: Re 1: When I run your command, even though it lists all recipes, it also displays a note about incompatible machine, allowing it to be grepped: `MACHINE=$YOUR_MACHINE bitbake-layers show-recipes -l my_layer -r | grep -v "incompatible with machine"`